# Updating a zone inside a form in Tapestry 5

Tags: java, ajax, tapestry

I've got a `Zone` inside a `Form`, the `Zone` is updated with a block containing input fields which I would like to bind to the parent `Form`. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work quite as easily as I hoped as I am greeted with the following error message.

```
The Description component must be enclosed by a Form component. [at classpath:...Page.tml, line 100]
```

A simplified version of the source `.tml` is below.

```html
<t:form t:id="editForm" t:context="item.id">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td><t:textField value="item.name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <t:block t:id="block">
            <tr class="person">
                <th>Description</th>
                <td><t:textField t:id="description" value="item.description"/></td>
            </tr>
         </t:block>
         <t:zone t:id="itemZone" id="itemZone"/>
         <t:actionlink t:id="item" zone="itemZone">Click me!</t:actionlink>
    </table>
</t:form>
```

Is there a way to do the binding and if not what other alternatives are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This answer is outdated, you can add form elements using the usual zone functionality [from Tapestry 5.2 on](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-1084). This method still works as well, though.**

#### Original answer, valid for Tapestry 5.0 and 5.1:

The [`FormInjector`](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5.1/tapestry-core/ref/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/FormInjector.html) component allows you to add form elements to an exising form. You will have to write some custom JS to trigger the form injection, though.

In your TML:

```
<div t:type="FormInjector" t:id="injector" position="below" />
```

You can trigger the injection in your JS code like this:

```
$('theClientIdOfMyFormInjector').trigger();
```

You can find the injector DIV inside your form by its class name (`myForm.down('div.t-forminjector')`).

The component class:

```
@Inject
private Block formFieldsBlock;

@OnEvent(component = "injector")
Block loadExtraFormFields() {
    return this.formFieldsBlock;
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can change context information on the fly? I am currently passing the back-end an id with t:context="item.id", but I am having trouble finding where I can dynamically change this.

Comment: @Ponzao: Sorry... change where to do what? (Maybe this would make a good new question?)

Comment: Yeah I'll make a new question, just a moment.

Comment: I added a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974282/modifying-context-information-in-tapestry-5-dynamically.